# Effective design to group Enum's to different conditions with many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

In Java, I'm using `Enum` and then using `EnumSet` to group various enum's representing similar behavior.

Something like :

```
enum MyConditions {
    condition_A;
    condition_B;
    condition_1;
    condition_100;
    condition_xyz;
    ... more ...

}

EnumSet<MyConditions> group1 = EnumSet.of(condition_A, condition_xyz);
EnumSet<MyConditions> group2 = EnumSet.of(condition_B, condition_xyz);
EnumSet<MyConditions> group3 = EnumSet.of(condition_xyz);
... and many more...
```

The reason for different `EnumSet` is I want to test if a particular condition belongs to group 1 or group 2 or group3 and so forth.

It feels the design is bit convulated as I've to keep making more and more `EnumSet` for different conditions, and the design does not support sub-grouping. For instance combining group1 & 2 to test for a parent condition.

Other proposal I've is to supply the group in the enum construction itself.

Something like :

```
enum MyConditions {
    condition_A(group1);
    condition_B(group2);
    condition_1;
    condition_100;
    condition_xyz(group1, group2);
    ... more ...

}
```

This is also not very good as this makes readibility of `Enum` an issue when there are multiple groups.

`Enums` are static data which correspond to some integer from third party API. Yes, i want to dynamically create condition-group relationships or if i am defining manually then at-least somewhat cleaner than how i am doing currently. Other than just finding if a particular condition is in a particular group, there are multiple groups which can represent a similar condition. For instance if caller is asking for a condition, and if that is not part of group 1, but group 2. We would want to say "no, its not part of group 1, but part of group2". This is assuming group1 and group2 were tagged as similar. But lets suppose there is a standalone group3, and if user asks is condition part of group3, we just want to say "no, its not part of group3"

Any ideas on what is a good design here?

Comment: We could use some background on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The reason for different EnumSet is I want to test if a particular condition belongs to group 1 or group 2 or group3 and so forth.

Comment: It would be useful to add a little bit of detail on what you want to achieve by *better design*. For example, do you want to dynamically create *condition-group* relationships. If so, how these relationships are formed? Will they be coming from a database or are result of some type of calculation?

Comment: `Enums` are static data which correspond to some integer from third party API. Yes, i want to dynamically create condition-group relationships or if i am defining manually then at-least somewhat cleaner than how i am doing currently. Other than just finding if a particular condition is in a particular group, there are multiple groups which can represent a similar condition. For instance if caller is asking for a condition, and if that is not part of group 1, but group 2. We would want to say "no, its not part of group 1, but part of group2"